# what to check for disabled settings for the app in notification center?

Tags: ios, objective-c

- I have a code like below.
- I went to notification center and disabled all alerts, badges, show on lock screen for my app
- But the code below still returns true when I expected false.
- What should I be checking for to get false for disabled settings for the app in notification center

  ```
  -(BOOL)pushEnabled 
  {
  BOOL enabled = NO;

  if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
  {
      enabled = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications];
  }
  else
  {
      UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
      enabled = types & UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert;
  }
  return enabled; }
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apple doc for `isRegisteredForRemoteNotificaitons` says the return is:

**YES if the app is registered for remote notifications and received its device token or NO if registration has not occurred, has failed, or has been denied by the user.**

So, if you successfully registered for remote notifications then `isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications` will return `YES` regardless of system settings.

If you want to check `UIUserNotificationSettings` then this should work:

```
UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSettings = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];
if (!notificationSettings || (notificationSettings.types == UIUserNotificationTypeNone)) {
    // not enabled
} else {
    // enabled
}
```

## EDIT:

If you're working with < iOS 8 then this should work:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(currentUserNotificationSettings)]){
    UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSettings = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];

    if (!notificationSettings || (notificationSettings.types == UIUserNotificationTypeNone)) {
            // not enabled
        } else {
            // enabled
        }
    } else {
        UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
        if (types) {
            // enabled
        } else {
            // not enabled
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this work in iOS 7 as well?...this will work in ios 8 I guess

Comment: I updated my answer to support iOS 7 as well. You will get a warning in Xcode that `UIRemoteNotificationType` is deprecated in iOS 8.

Comment: You will only get warnings about deprecated APIs if the API was deprecated on or before your Deployment Target.